# How to position a button over an image in CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

All I need is to place the button on the image. I am practicing at the W3schools CSS. I  have altered the original code in the link given.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

I am providing screenshot of altered code.

[image]

code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid green;
    }

img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div > 
<img src="w3css.gif" width="100%" height="100%">
<button> button </button>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML/CSS/JS snippet against screen

Comment: Include the code directly in your question. You can create a executable snippet by using the button (`<>`) in the editor.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question nor question mark. What's your question?

Comment: Make your img position `absolute`.  Then it will flow in the upper left corner and the space of the image is not being blocked for other elements anymore, so the button will be on top of the image.

Comment: In your code if you remove `h2` and place your button, you will get button top of the image. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTBWKLLREYQL

Comment: Positioning with absolute works according to the viewport. First I want an image according   to the div, that's why i used relative, then i wish to place a button on image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To position any element on top of another requires making it a layer like this.

```css
.wrapper {
position: relative;
}
.myLayer {
  position: absolute; /* becomes a layer */
  left: 0; /* relative to its parent wrapper */
  top:40px; /* relative to its parent wrapper */
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--other stuff here - ie image or whatever -->
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613585574494-200c873926e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
  <button type="button" class="myLayer">
    Position me relative to the wrapper
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a very good answer Steve.  Further, can we declare zIndex to one also? & In the button(myLayer), the absolute position is placed according to the parent div(wrapper).  So, such positioning  will happen according to the immediate parent or root parent?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should add `position: relative;` to div style

Then style the button with `position: absolute;`

As a result your complete code must be like that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid green;
    position: relative; /* Add this */
  }
  img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  /* Create button style */
  button {
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute; /* Add this */
    left: 50px; /* Also add this for position: absolute to work properly */
    top: 50px; /* Also add this for position: absolute to work properly */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/w3css.gif" width="100%" height="100%">
    <button type="button" name="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the button on top of the image, you can make your `img` **position to absolute**, like this:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then the button will go to the upper left corner and the remaining space of the image is not being blocked for other elements.

Comment: Abhirajshri, I am using a div (as a parent element) with some dimensions (rectangular box); then i place an image (as a child element) to be fit into that div,  then i want a button (as another child element)  which can be placed anywhere on the image. Now help me here if you have understood it. I mean which element should be declare as relative and which one is absolute.